# TypeORM migration:generate failing

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm running

```
npm run typeorm migration:generate -n UPDATE-campaign-project-field-type
```

and getting error: `Missing required argument: n`

It was just working yesterday. I've tried with `--name` as well as `-n`. This makes no sense - the argument is right there. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can try `migration:create -n` instead `migration:generate -n` https://typeorm.io/migrations#creating-a-new-migration

Comment: Thanks for that - I should have mentioned, I've tried that, as well - get the same error.

Comment: Well, I ran `yarn upgrade typeorm` and now `migration:create` works - `migration:generate` still does not. It must have something to do with the version.